# Unmerged files error in sourcetree

Tags: sourcetree

On trying to do a pull in source tree I am getting the following error:

```
error: Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
```

I am new to deployments and source tree. So I tried to reset the current branch to a previous commit which was successful. But still I am getting the same error on doing pull. I even tried to delete the local repo and create new one. But the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of reset did you do? it was anything other than a `hard reset` then changed files may still show up. Also check your working copy for uncommitted changes and discard them.